# JMeter POST response body is null

Tags: java, api, jmeter, postman, performance-testing

Response code is 200 with error count 0 but response body is null.
PostMan Request: i hit the api from postman with this request body.

```
{"body": {
"distance": 3466567.8,
"latitude": 45.7,
"longitude": 80.7}}
```

Postman response: I got this reponse on postman.

```
 "requestId": "LME2206071048390000193004",
"msgId": "LME2206071048390000191004",
"accDate": null,
"startDateTime": [
    2022,
    6,
    7,
    10,
    48,
    39,
    100000000
],
"locale": "zh_CN",
"routeInfo": "LME"
.......................
```

Now if i hit the same API with same request body from the JMeter, i got the below mentioned response.

```
{
"msgId": null,
"source": null,
"locale": null,
"body": null,
"userId": null,
"uri": null,
"accDate": null,
"startDateTime": null,
"requestId": null,
"msgCd": "SYS00001",
"msgInfo": null}
................
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot "help me how to resolve this issue" unless you share the Postman and JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configurations

It might be the case you forgot something obvious, i.e. sending a relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header

In general if your request works fine in Postman you can just record it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) (it's better to use [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#basic-instructions) for this)
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman
5. That's it, JMeter should intercept the request and generate the relevant HTTP Request sampler and friends so you can [replay it with increased load](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling)

Comment: thank you  so much for answering the question.
Dmitri T, i tried HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder method but this is not working in my case i don't know why. 
and as far as headers are concerned, i used application/json content type in both postman and jmeter. everything is same but it's not working, there should be a little issue in this case i i'm unable to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Above mentioned Issue is resolved.
The main issue was the order of the fields in the request body.
I was sending this request from postman and it was working fine.

```
{ "body": {
"distance": 3466567.8,
"latitude": 45.7,
"longitude": 80.7
}}
```

And when i send this same request from jmeter it was not working fine. i was getting null values in the fields of response body. Then i realized and change the order of fields in the request body as according to my business logic and it works.

```
{
"body": {
"latitude": 45.7,
"longitude": 80.7,
"distance": 3466567.8
}}
```